# Tried to make a chat bot for discord but it doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a discord bot in python (discord.py).
I was trying to make a chat command for my bot, but it doesn't give a respond back and also not a error.
I asked my friend but he also didn't how to make it and what was wrong with it.
My goal is to get the bot to respond back, for example if I say hello it responds back with hello + me mentioned.

This is my code:

````
async def chat(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Chat mode ON")
    hi = "hello", "hi", "hallo"
    hgh = "how are you doing", "how are you doing?", "hoe gaat het?","how are you"
    exit = "bye", "exit", "Bye","Exit"
    invite = "invite", "can i get your invite link?"
    
    
    msg = await  bot.wait_for("message" )

    if msg.content == hi:
        await ctx.send("Hello " + ctx.message.author.mention)
    if msg.content == hgh:
        await ctx.send("Im doing as long as my script is running, how are you? " + ctx.message.author.mention)
    if msg.content == exit:
        await ctx.send("Bye, hope to see you again soon " + ctx.message.author.mention)
    if msg.content == invite:
        await ctx.send("This is my invite link: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=858775426490957845&permissions=8&scope=bot " + ctx.message.author.mention)```



If you know what is wrong with it and how to fix it please let me know, it would mean a lot to me.
````

Comment: You have to use an `on_message(message)` event in order to listen to messages.

Comment: You're comparing a list to a string. Use `in` instead. -> `if msg.content in hi:` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on_message(message) if you want a chatbot, You made a command called "chat".

```
@bot.event
async def on_message (message):
 

if "hi" in message.content.lower():
    await ctx.send("Hello " + ctx.message.author.mention)
elif "hgh" in message.content.lower():
    await ctx.send("Im doing as long as my script is running, how are you? " + ctx.message.author.mention)
elif "invite" in message.content.lower():

    await ctx.send("This is my invite link: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=858775426490957845&permissions=8&scope=bot " + ctx.message.author.mention)
```

Comment: if you need more help then just comment

Comment: can i also add the variable's of hi, hgh, exit and invite?

Comment: what? why would u need variables of them?

Comment: or what would you use them for?

Comment: That if you say hello it sees it as hi, then I don't have to write them all down